# Excel VBA: Determine if range is horizontal or vertical

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a function that, among others, has a range as input.
This range will be 1 row by ? columns or 1 columns by ? rows. In other words, it will be "one dimensional" - either horizontal or vertical.

Based on whether it is H or V, certain calculations will be made.
How can I determine if the range that is passed is horizontal or vertical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
Function RangeIsVertical(rng As Range) As Boolean
    RangeIsVertical = IIf(rng.Columns.Count = 1, 1, 0)
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print RangeIsVertical(Range("A1")) //True
    Debug.Print RangeIsVertical(Range("A1:A10")) //True
    Debug.Print RangeIsVertical(Range("A1:B2")) //False
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent!
Thanks Alex

Comment: Can be shortened to `RangeIsVertical = (rng.Columns.Count = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If `Range.Columns.Count=1` then it's vertical.  If `Range.Rows.Count=1`, it's horizontal (assuming, like you said, you only have either rows or columns).

Comment: Thanks!

Looks like an awesome way of doing it.

However, I made a testing range J34:J37 with values
1
2
3
4

and did Range.Width and .Height on that. It returned 30 and 54, respectively. Neither is equal to 1 :(

Comment: This refers to the pixel width and height.